# useEffect() function runs only once, store is updated later (React hooks)

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I have an application where I am fetching the store as such:

```
const user_data = useSelector(state => state.user_data);
```

I have a `useEffect()` function right after that that assigns certain state objects to the data received from the store.

```
useEffect(() => {
  setName(user_data.name);
}, []);
```

The store is being set by something like:

```
await dispatch(save_user_info(res.data.response));
props.history.push("/setting/dashboard");
```

Now the problem is, `user_data` is empty when `useEffect` first runs.
It gets populated afterwards, but `useEffect` just runs once.

The page is redirected to the new component before the store is updated, so when the page loads first, it does not have the store data.

How can I make `useEffect` run again if the data from the store is returned?

Comment: In your useEffect dependency you need to add state.user_data as a watcher, so whenever its updated the useEffect will execute. i.e useEffect(() => {
  setName(user_data.name);
}, state.user_data);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you keep the 2nd argument of useEffect empty it will run every time the component updates.

```
useEffect(() => {
  setName(user_data.name);
});
```

in your case it runs if variables mentioned in this array [](which is empty) are changed.

or you can do this

```
useEffect(() => {
  setName(user_data.name);
},[user_data]); // or props.user_data , howsoever you can refer to that
```